# Is it possible to write doc for function/class (non-ui elements) in Storybook?

Tags: storybook

Storybook is great to showcase and document components, but i also have some utility functions and class that i would like to add to storybook, is it possible make use of its controls as those function params?

Comment: Please explain more about your use case

Comment: Basically what is the best way to document a function in storybook, as it is only made for component documentation

Comment: Just add an MDX file and write your code in it, I've done it in my projects, I can show you my structure

Comment: Yes please share, i am a newbie to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For writing docs for non-UI elements just use an MDX file.

debounce function:

```
import { FnType } from 'types';
import { generateError } from 'utils';

let timer;

export default function debounce(fn: FnType, timeout: number = 300) {
  try {
    return (...args) => {
      if (!timer) fn.apply(this, args);
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => (timer = undefined), timeout);
    };
  } catch (e) {
    generateError(e);
  }
}
```

**debounce.stories.mdx**:

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs';

<Meta title="Debounce" />

## Debounce the execution of a given function

### Syntax: debounce(fn , timeout)

- fn: callback function
- timeout: timout value in ms

#### Usage:

const doSomeThing = () => {console.log("doing...")}

debounce (doSomeThing , 300)
```

**and here is my utils folder (non-UI)**

[image]

**NOTE**
I'm using storybook version 6

[image]

Comment: can u also share the screenshot in storybook?

Comment: you are just manually documenting your function in markdown, there is nothing in there that generates documentation from your component code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the documentation to be generated code first, you can do that using the Typedoc library

```
npm install --save-dev typedoc typedoc-plugin-markdown
```

Then use it with the typedoc-plugin-markdown. This will convert your JSDocs to markdown files.

```
npx typedoc --plugin typedoc-plugin-markdown
```

Now you can link the generated .md files in another .mdx file using the Documentation tag like this

```
// ExampleService.stories.mdx
import { Description } from "@storybook/addon-docs";
import SomeInterface from "path/to/file.md";

<Description markdown={SomeInterface} />
```

See this thread: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/discussions/17646

Currently there is no direct conversion possible and this is a bit messy, since you cannot directly convert to .mdx, however I prefer this option a lot more then harcoding documentation in .mdx files, which is very prone to error and will likely lead to outdated documentation (I would certainly forget how to update)